# Cannot load Sidekiq with nested module in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

For a Rails project I'm working on, I'm having an issue with loading Sidekiq and having nested modules in the lib directory.

my `lib/scraper/v2.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'scraper/v2/client'

module Scraper
  module V2
  end
end
```

my `lib/scraper/v2/client.rb` looks like this:

```
module Scraper
  module V2
    class Client

      def initialize
        ...
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I then have a Sidekiq job in the `jobs` directory that looks like this:

```
class RefreshTokenJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    client = Scraper::V2::Client.new
    ...
  end
end
```

If I run `bundle exec sidekiq` with this configuration, Sidekiq starts, but running `Scraper::V2::Client.new` form the Rails console returns:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Scraper::V2
```

If I add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to my application.rb file, I can run `Scraper::V2::Client.new`, but starting Sidekiq gives me and uninitialized constant error from a completely different file (within `app/jobs/concerns/`).

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Rails autoloading only works if files are named correctly, meaning your module should hang out in `scraper/v2.rb`, not `lib/scraper_v2.rb`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: I've placed it in `lib/scraper/v2.rb` now. The latter requires `scraper/v2/client`. However, I am still getting the following error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Scraper::V2`

Comment: Does `ApplicationJob` inherit from `ActiveJob::Base` ? I'm sure it does but it's worth asking. Do you have any other classes or modules named `Scraper`? Also make sure you restart your Rails server.

Comment: I believe it does, yes. I have it configured in `application.rb` with the following: `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` and I think Rails 5 automatically allows ActiveJob to interface with Sidekiq this way. Yes I've restarted the rails console as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow Rails' conventions for naming files if you want Rails autoloading to work correctly.

For a module named Scraper::V2, it should be in a file named `scraper/v2.rb`, not `scraper_v2.rb`.

Comment: V2 is actually the nested module within Scraper. What I want is to initialize the client with `Scraper::V2::Client.new`. Is `scraper/v2/client.rb` incorrect?

Comment: I've placed `scraper_v2.rb` in `lib/scraper/v2.rb` now. The latter requires scraper/v2/client. However, I am still getting the following error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Scraper::V2`. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: did you restart your server and/or spring?

Comment: I have restarted, yes.